# the use of __new__(self, socket_buffer=None)

Tags: python

### Reading the Packet Sniffing in black hat python, some of the codes are:

```
def __new__(self, socket_buffer=None):
return self.from_buffer_copy(socket_buffer)
```

---

- why 'socket_buffer' is set to 'None'?
- does it mean empty the variable 'socket_buffer' first, then put the content in the buffer to 'socket_buffer' via 'from_buffer_copy'?

Comment: You should begin by reading [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

socket_buffer is non-required parameter for this func, and if it's not passed in in the func call, it will be set to None